# How to count only different lines?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am starting with Python so in a file I would like to count the lines that are different.

A part of the text:

```
filter:usergroup xxxx username Joshep
filter:usergroup xxxx username Mark
filter:usergroup xxxx username Amy
filter:usergroup aaaaa username Chris
filter:usergroup bbb username Chris
```

I can count the diffent number of username binds with.

```
with open(arch_path) as archive:
    for line in archive:
        if 'filter:usergroup' in line:
            filter_c=filter_c+1
```

But I would like to count that in the text there are 3 different usergroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd accumulate the group names to a set (which will only retain one element per unique name), but print out its size after going over the file:

```
group_names = set()
with open(arch_path) as archive:
    for line in archive:
        if 'filter:usergroup' in line:
            group_name = line.split()[1]
            group_names.add(group_name)

filter_c = len(group_names)
```